# Circleci. SDK location not found

Tags: android, automation, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

Options mentioned in similar questions didn't help for me. That's why I'm creating question.

When trying to build project on CircleCi I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exited with code 1
```

I've tried to take configuration file from here:  `https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-android/`

I've also tried to use default configuration file, when building a project.

I've set ANDROID Home variable, I've checked local.properties file. Everything is correct.

Can anybody help?

My `config.yml` file:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
        - run:
        name: Chmod permissions #if permission for Gradlew Dependencies fail, use this. 
       command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
```

Answer (score 0):

go to app directory -> go to android directory -> create a  file named `local.properties`

then add :

`sdk.dir = /home/user-name/Android/Sdk`

NOTE: replace sdk address with your's